# Are NHibernate Projections.SqlProjection and Projections.SqlFunction portable across databases?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have CriteriaAPI query with some projections (*Projections.SqlProjection*). First parameter in *Projections.SqlProjection* method is sql string. I'd like to change the query to do it portable across databases. What should I do with sql string parameter in *Projections.SqlProjection* method? Should I re-write sql to hql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the provided sql is ANSI SQL, and the target databases support the used syntax, it is already portable. When database specific features are used, you need to rewrite it. It may be hard, because there is a reason why native SQL had been used. There is a chance that the original author just didn't know that there is a nice solution within hibernate.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan, almost that is it. Maybe you know, can I replace _SqlProjection_ on some HQL projection (something like "Projections.HqlProjection") and how can I do that?

Comment: I mean, I don't want to re-write all the query on HQL, just one projection.

Comment: Projection and SqlProjection is a concept of criteria API. There is no HQL to be used when using criteria.